# What's the best way to make the overlapping item in RecyclerView?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I need to make `RecyclerView` with so content:

[image: Sample]

But I don't know how to better make it... I think to use a custom divider (info item) for this purpose but I don't sure that it's a good idea. Maybe, who knows another ways. I'll glad for any help and advices.

P.S. I cannot use 3 items because I need to save the touch area for each item as large as without the overlapping item.

Comment: Hi! Have you found any solution?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [this](https://github.com/Ramotion/folding-cell-android) library if you can, To display more info in same list.
suggestion to make it better. not only option.

Comment: Thank you but it isn't that I need, unfortunately. And I need to support API 8+.